# rbenv build failed , while trying to install ruby version 1.9.3-p327

Tags: ruby, rbenv

Update:

I was able to install 2.0.0-p451 and 1.9.3-p545 sucessfully,
However I am still not able to install 1.9.3-p327 and when I tried to install 1.8.7-p375 I get the following error message:

Checking out svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_8_7...
Installing ruby-1.8.7-p375...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20140324164042.15847
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20140324164042.15847.log

Last 10 log lines:
ossl_pkey_ec.c:815: error: 'EC_GROUP_new_curve_GF2m' undeclared (first use in this function)
ossl_pkey_ec.c:815: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ossl_pkey_ec.c:815: error: for each function it appears in.)
ossl_asn1.c: In function 'ossl_asn1_decode0':
ossl_asn1.c:726: warning: passing argument 1 of 'ASN1_get_object' from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:944: note: expected 'const unsigned char **' but argument is of type 'unsigned char **'
make[1]: *** [ossl_pkey_ec.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20140324164042.15847/ruby-1.8.7-p375/ext/openssl'
make: *** [all] Error 1

Could anyone please tell me why this is happening...

---

I am trying to install like this: rbenv install 1.9.3-p327

And the results are:

Downloading yaml-0.1.5.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/24f6093c1e840ca5df2eb09291a1dbf1
Installing yaml-0.1.5...
Installed yaml-0.1.5 to /home/user/atatachar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327

Downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/96118e856b502b5d7b3a4398e6c6e98c
Installing ruby-1.9.3-p327...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887.log

Last 10 log lines:
Generating docs for compound YYSTYPE...
Generating docs for compound zone...
Generating docs for compound zstream...
Generating docs for nested compound zstream::zstream_funcs...
Generating namespace index...
Generating namespace member index...
Generating graph info page...
Generating file index...
Generating example index...
Generating file member index...

I tried doing the following things to make rbenv work:

1) Completely remove .rbenv directory and reinstalled rbenv.

2) Tried installing other versions.

3) Tried to install rbenv in a temporary directory

4) I also took a look into the log file
and the following looked suspicious to me:

-> Version of /tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/compar.c : linking transcoder escape.so
(null)

There are a lot of files with (null) like above.

The build process continues after these null until these following statements:

/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ext/ripper/ripper.y:18: Warning: include file ruby/ruby.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ext/ripper/ripper.y:19: Warning: include file ruby/st.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ext/ripper/ripper.y:20: Warning: include file ruby/encoding.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/regenc.h:33: Warning: include file ruby/config.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/regenc.h:34: Warning: include file ruby/defines.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/regenc.h:40: Warning: include file ruby/oniguruma.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ext/ripper/ripper.y:26: Warning: include file stdio.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ext/ripper/ripper.y:27: Warning: include file errno.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ext/ripper/ripper.y:28: Warning: include file ctype.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
/tmp/ruby-build.20140324141730.6887/ruby-1.9.3-p327/id.c:12: Warning: include file ruby/ruby.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?

And the build continues with the last statement being :
Generating file member index....

I am not able to make out anything from the log file. Could anybody please help me..

Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case , remove .rbenv

try this :

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just tried your command... I am getting the same BUILD FAILED message as before.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you gist/pastebing the log ?

Comment: met with almost similar issue. I detailed what helped here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394316/ruby-install-fails-when-installing-ruby-2-6-x-and-3-0-x-on-mac-osx-11-6